# re.pl: Variable not properly scoped inside block

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop

Example:

```
~ $ re.pl
$ { my $abc = 10 ; $abc }
10
$ $abc
10
$
```

Is this a documented gotcha?

Comment: Is it actually Perl ou a shell question?

Comment: Hi pascal. See http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Devel-REPL-1.003012/lib/Devel/REPL.pm

Comment: OK... the original example did not mention REPL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in [Lexical::Persistence](http://p3rl.org/Lexical%3a%3aPersistence), which [Devel::REPL](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aREPL) uses to manage the lexical environment persisting across multiple `eval`s.

Here's a demonstration of the bug without Devel::REPL. This code incorrectly produces the value of `$abc`, 10, even though it's in an inner scope.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lexical::Persistence;

my $environment = Lexical::Persistence->new;
$environment->call(sub {
    my $foo = shift;
    { my $abc = 10 };
    return $foo;
});

print $environment->get_context('_')->{'$abc'};
```

I've reported a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=68699) against the module, we'll see what happens!

It's also worth noting that Matt Trout (the primary author of Devel::REPL)'s new lexical persistence module, [Eval::WithLexicals](http://p3rl.org/Eval%3a%3aWithLexicals) does *not* suffer from this problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Eval::WithLexicals;

my $environment = Eval::WithLexicals->new;
print $environment->eval('{ my $abc = 10 ; $abc }'), "\n";
print $environment->eval('$abc'), "\n";
```

produces `10` as expected, then the second eval throws the expected `Global symbol "$abc" requires explicit package name` error.

Comment: Looking a bit deeper at Lexical::Persistence's code, it seems like the bug is actually in [PadWalker](http://p3rl.org/PadWalker)'s `peek_sub`, which is the canonical way to get the lexical variables of a subroutine. `warn Dumper(peek_sub(sub { my $foo = shift; { my $abc = 10 }; return $foo; }));` has entries for `$foo` and `$abc`. Eval::WithLexicals does not suffer the same problem because it doesn't use PadWalker.

Answer (score 3):

`$a` and `$b` are special variables used for sorting. see `perldoc -f sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$a` or `$b`.

From [Perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (Perl predefined variables) documentation:

> **$a**
>    **$b**
>
> Special package variables when using **`sort()`**, [see sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html). Because of this specialness $a and $b don't need to be declared (using **`use vars`** , or **`our()`**) even when using the **`strict 'vars'`** pragma. Don't lexicalize them with **`my $a`** or **`my $b`** if you want to be able to use them in the **`sort()`** comparison block or function.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen if you run your code directly in the Perl interpreter:

```
$ perl -we '{ my $abc = 10 ; print "($abc)\n"; }; print "($abc)\n";'
Name "main::abc" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
(10)
Use of uninitialized value $abc in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
()
```

May be you have found a bug in [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aREPL).